# Angular: next and previous Document view

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I am currently developing a Search with a single Document view.
I got a list with all Documents ID´s the matches my query (this.hits = ["809", "807", "812"])

In the Document view, I want to navigate to the next and previous documents. this works only the first time. When the next Document-view is loading, the nextItem and prevItem is undefined. I don't know why.

I have stored all document id´s in a queryStoreService

The single Document is viewed in  DocumentViewComponent

**DocumentView**

```
export class DocumentViewComponent implements OnInit {

    hits: string[];
    prevItem: string;
    nextItem: string;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private hitsStore: QuerystoreService,

      ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // current Document ID
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');


        // get all ids from querysearch
        this.hits = this.hitsStore.getAllHits();

            for (let i = 0; i < this.hits.length ; i++) {
                // check if current id is in array
                if ( this.hits[i] === id ) {
                this.nextItem = this.hits[i + 1];
                this.prevItem = this.hits[i - 1];
                }
             }



            // loading single Documentview
            this.http.documentById(id).subscribe(res => {
                .....
            })


      }


      prev() {
        window.open('/document/' + this.prevItem, '_self');
        window.location.reload();
      }

      next() {
        window.open('/suche#/document/' + this.nextItem , '_self');
        window.location.reload();
      }
}
```

**QueryService**

```
export class QuerystoreService {

  allObjects: string[] = [];
  allHits: any;

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('keine Query');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }




  gettingHits(message: any) {
    const allObjects = [];
    message.hits.forEach((hit: string) => {
      allObjects.push(hit['_id']);
  });
    console.log(allObjects);
    this.allHits = allObjects;
    return this.allObjects;
  }


  public getAllHits(): any[] {
    return this.allHits;
  }



}
```

Comment: can you show stackblitz link?

Comment: What I understand from your question, you have a component where you have id in your router parameter. you want to load something with http call with this Id. After tht clicking prev() and next() will navigate you to the next and previous page. Am I right? as you only call getAllHits() in your service and return allHits. but allHits is undefined. How do you get those response